# Regex for extracting comma delimited numbers in brackets

Tags: php, regex

String:

```
lorem ipsum 999
[id:284,286]
[id:28]
```

Block in brackets may contain a lot of numbers.

Regex:

```
\[id:(\d+)(,\d+)*\]
```

What I'd like to see:

```
284
286
28
```

Solution using PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/\[id:(.*)\]/', $input, $ids);
if (strpos($ids[1][0], ',')) {
    $ids = explode(',', $ids[1][0]);
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        echo $id . "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo $ids[1][0];
}
```

But is it possible using regex without explode()?

Comment: You have a comma inside the 2nd group, move it out. `\[id:(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?\]`. However, what about `[id:284,286,289,345]`? I think you should just get  a substring with the numbers and split with a comma.

Comment: Would this [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS4kR9/2) help you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew string may contain more values

Comment: then use `*` instead of `?` in the regex of @WiktorStribiżew..`\[id:(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*\]`

Comment: No need in regex. Use `var s = "[id:284,286,566,3467]";
alert(s.substring(4, s.length - 1).split(","));`

Comment: @lbarros input data may contain other strings and this block should be indicated by [id:(numbers)]

Comment: Виталий, is that a *single* multiline string? Ok, I will post what I think can help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew single

Comment: Aha, so it is PHP. Please add the tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, PCRE does not remember repeated groups, thus, you either do it in 2 steps (with the `explode`), or use a `\G` based regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `explode` way is perhaps the best. Unfortunately, PCRE does not remember repeated groups, thus, you either do it in 2 steps (with the `explode`), or use a `\G` based regex. Here is a safer regex than the one you are using (if there are no spaces in between the numbers):

```
$input = "lorem ipsum 999 [id:284,286] [id:28]"; 
preg_match_all('~\[id:([\d,]*)]~', $input, $ids);
foreach ($ids[1] as $id) {
    print_r(explode(',', $id)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/tNAo42)

The `'~\[id:([\d,]*)]~'` regex matches `[id:` and then matches and captures into Group 1 zero or more (due to `*` *0+ occurrences* quantifier) digits (`\d`) or `,`s.

If you need a one-regex solution, in PHP, if you process *individual* strings, you can make use of a `\G` based regex that you can leverage to set up the leading boundary and then match the consecutive numbers:

```
'~(?:\[id:|(?!^)\G,)\K\d+~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ4kC7/2) and this [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/HVtTbS):

```
$re = '~(?:\[id:|(?!^)\G,)\K\d+~'; 
$strs = array("lorem ipsum 999", "[id:284,286]", "[id:28]"); 
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    preg_match_all($re, $s, $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:\[id:|(?!^)\G,)` - match the `[id:` literal character sequence or the end of each successful match with `(?!^)\G` with a comma after it
- `\K` - omit the matched value
- `\d+` - only match 1+ digits

If there can be whitespace between the digits, add `\s*` after (and perhaps, before) the comma.

Comment: I suspect you wanted to get all with `(?:,?(\d+))*`, right? That can work in Python regex module, Boost, and .NET. Not in PHP.

Comment: I added another `explode` based solution with an IMHO safer regex.

Comment: preg_match_all('~\[id:([\d,]*)]~', $input, $ids); That's exactly what I'm looking for!